# Regular expressions with sed (extracting capturing groups)

Tags: regex, sed

From the output of:

```
$ pyenv virtualenvs
```

I want to extract with **sed** the names of the virtual environments as well their path. The same for the default environment is marked with an asterisk. The results look like this:

```
 3.6.3/envs/venv_1 (created from /home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3)
* anaconda3-5.0.0 (created from /home/user/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.0.0)
 venv_py3.6.3__test_01 (created from /home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3)
```

With PCRE as FLAVOR:

```
^\*\s([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]*)\s\(created\sfrom\s([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-\/]*)
```

I can capture both groups without problem:

Group 1: **anaconda3-5.0.0**

Group 2: **/home/user/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.0.0**

(tested on https://regex101.com)

but I cannot make it work with sed.

What I've managed so far is e.g. for the default environment to extract the name with:

```
sed -e 's/^\*\s\(.*\)\s(created\(.*\)/\1/
```

anaconda3-5.0.0

but for the path I get with:

```
sed -e 's/^\*\s\(.*\)\s(created\sfrom\s\(.*\)/\2/'
```

/home/user/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.0.0)

namely there is also a parenthesis at the right end. I know this is not the correct approach but I couldn't make it better so far.

Any ideas how can make it work with sed?

**UPDATE:**

As of now I have this:

for the names:

```
$ pyenv virtualenvs | sed -r 's/\(created\s*from\s*//g;s/\)//g;s/^\s*//g' | awk '{print $1}'
```

for the paths:

```
$ pyenv virtualenvs | sed -r 's/\(created\s*from\s*//g;s/\)//g;s/^\s*//g' | awk '{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a simple perl oneliner:

**Given:**

```
cat file
 3.6.3/envs/venv_1 (created from /home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3)
* anaconda3-5.0.0 (created from /home/user/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.0.0)
 venv_py3.6.3__test_01 (created from /home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3)
```

**Running:**

```
cat file | perl -ane 'print "$1\n$2\n" if m#^\*?\h+(\S+)\h+\(created from ([\w/.-]+)#'
3.6.3/envs/venv_1
/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3
anaconda3-5.0.0
/home/user/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.0.0
venv_py3.6.3__test_01
/home/user/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3
```

Of course, replace `cat file` with `pyenv virtualenvs`

**Regex explanation:**

```
m#                      : match, regex delimiter
    ^                   : beginning of line
      \*?               : an optional asterisk
      \h+               : 1 or more horizontal spaces (i.e. space or tab)
      (\S+)             : group 1, 1 or more non space characters
      \h+               : 1 or more horizontal spaces (i.e. space or tab)
      \(created from    : literally
      ([\w/.-]+)        : group 2, 1 or more word char, slash, dot, minus
#                       : regex delim
```

Comment: Thanks. I can get the default name and path with this, but how about the others?

Comment: @coverflower: Sorry I didn't well understand. See my edit edit, is it OK?

Comment: The advantage of this is that Perl regexes actually _are_ PCRE, as in the original test, while sed's POSIX Basic regular expressions are far away from that.

Comment: You might have issues with paths that use other characters... the following regex is probably more forgiving: `^\*? (.*?) \(created from (.*?)\)$`